# Why is Android socket reading so slow periodically?

Tags: java, android, sockets, inputstream

The socket is created as following:

```
Socket socket = new Socket();
socket.setReuseAddress(true);
socket.setSoTimeout(iTimeout);
socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(InetAddress.getByName(uri.getHost()), iPort), 6000);
socket.setReceiveBufferSize(iReceiveBufferSize); //iReceiveBufferSize = 1024*256
final InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
```

A debug method was created and tested just for the sake of asking this question:

```
public void SocketDebug(InputStream isSocketInput)
{
    try {
        byte[] abBuffer = new byte[1024*256];
        for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            long lStart = System.currentTimeMillis();
            int iRead = isSocketInput.read(abBuffer, 1024 * 10, 1024 * 128);
            int iElapse = (int)(System.currentTimeMillis() - lStart);
            if(iElapse > 100)
            {
                utility.logd("Debug", "i:" + i + " iElapse:" + iElapse + " iRead:" + iRead);
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {

    }
}
```

Here is a part of what recorded by logcat:

```
01-Jun  37:26.8 i:9     iElapse:234 iRead:1448
01-Jun  37:29.5 i:114   iElapse:299 iRead:1448
01-Jun  37:29.8 i:126   iElapse:298 iRead:1448
01-Jun  37:30.1 i:132   iElapse:300 iRead:1448
01-Jun  37:30.4 i:139   iElapse:283 iRead:1448
01-Jun  37:30.7 i:146   iElapse:287 iRead:1448
01-Jun  37:31.0 i:160   iElapse:269 iRead:1448
01-Jun  37:31.3 i:169   iElapse:251 iRead:44888
01-Jun  37:31.5 i:170   iElapse:192 iRead:1448
01-Jun  37:31.7 i:185   iElapse:170 iRead:1448
01-Jun  37:32.0 i:198   iElapse:171 iRead:1448
01-Jun  37:32.2 i:217   iElapse:158 iRead:1448
01-Jun  37:32.5 i:240   iElapse:162 iRead:1448
01-Jun  37:32.7 i:259   iElapse:135 iRead:1448
01-Jun  37:33.0 i:281   iElapse:103 iRead:1448
01-Jun  37:34.2 i:324   iElapse:826 iRead:1448
01-Jun  37:34.4 i:330   iElapse:233 iRead:1448
01-Jun  37:34.7 i:336   iElapse:264 iRead:1448
01-Jun  37:35.0 i:341   iElapse:299 iRead:1448
01-Jun  37:35.3 i:346   iElapse:300 iRead:1448
01-Jun  37:35.6 i:352   iElapse:297 iRead:1448
01-Jun  37:36.0 i:354   iElapse:317 iRead:21720
01-Jun  37:36.3 i:355   iElapse:304 iRead:13032
```

The data source is a video stream server.  Most of the time, isSocketInput.read() takes only 1 to 3 ms (not shown in the above log). However, periodically it takes 100 to 1000 ms. Looking at the red bytes count, apparently 1448 is the TCP payload. All the numbers of red byte are multiples of 1448.  One may think it may take so long for the server to send a TCP packet. What is hard to understand is that isSocketInput.read() sometimes reads so many packets (e.g. 31 packets = 44888 bytes) and takes so long to return.  Is it supposed to return as soon as possible when there is any data?

When SocketDebug() is run, all other threads of the app essentially enter sleep (i.e. in loops containing Thread.sleep()).

Could anyone offer a tip on the possible causes for the long socket reading time?

**Update (2015-06-03):**

The above test was done with an Android tablet with a single-core CPU (Asus MeMO). When the test was done with a low end generic Android tablet with a quad-core CPU (AGPTek TP714AQ), the time used by isSocketInput.read() improved dramatically. The number of long elapses dropped to zero after the first 200 iterations. Even during the initial 200 or so iterations, there are only a handful of long elapses (> 100 ms).

At this point of time, I think the long elapses with the single-core CPU device are mostly caused by what referred to in the answer as **"process or thread got rescheduled"** which happens much more frequently on a single-core CPU device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can't read any faster than data is arriving, and that can't happen any faster than data is being sent. Don't blame the receiving code, blame the sender, or the network.

When you you get a larger number of bytes it is probably after you blocked for longer, and more data arrived before your process or thread got rescheduled again. You can't control that either from your code.

Notes:

- You should call `setReceiveBufferSize()` *before* connecting, not afterwards. That way window scaling can take effect.
- Calling `setReuseAddress()` if you're not specifying a local port is pointless.

Comment: Thank you so much for your prompt answer.  I did not tell the whole story because I thought the question was long enough and wanted to keep the content highly relevant.  I am looking into this because I am getting long delays.  I found the bottleneck is getting the data, not processing. A Windows app streams from exactly the same server using exactly the same URI and protocol, but it does not have the delay. I have been suspecting the cause is what you mentioned "your process or thread got rescheduled". This is why I paused other threads for testing. Is there a way to confirm this?

Comment: I would be surprised if it was a scheduling issue, unless your box is regularly overloaded with ready threads.  What L1 link do you have?  WiFi? 3G?

Comment: I suggest you try it with the receive buffer size set in the right place. You will find a considerable difference *if* it isn't the sender.

Comment: It is strange I am not getting notifications of new comments.  @MartinJames The connection is 802.11g.

Comment: I changed the receive buffer statement position as soon as I saw your answer, but unfortunately it does not seem to make any difference to this problem.  What has made dramatic difference is a quad-core generic tablet.  The reported test was done with an Asus MeMO single-core tablet.  When I ran the test with a generic quad-core low end tablet, the number of long elapses dropped dramatically. Actually dropped to zero after the first 100 or so iterations of the loop.

Comment: Thank you all for the tips.  It is late here. I will create some trace reports tomorrow to see if they can provide any clue.

Comment: I could not find any clue in the thread tab and profiling traces of Android Device Monitor.  Another very interesting observation: the frequency of long elapses increases dramatically (occurs almost every other iteration) after I added Thread.sleep(10) to the loop.  I originally thought it might help. Again, the quad-core low end tablet (AGPTek TP714AQ) has few long elapses. Actually, at this moment, it often has zero long elapses from the 1000 iterations of the loop.  Please let me know your thought.  I am ready to take a guess of this whole thing and accept your answer.

Comment: Why on earth would you add `Thread.sleep()` to a blocking read loop? How could it possibly help? It is completely and utterly pointless: literally a waste of time. And it can slow down the sender as well. Don't just fiddle around.